# Bootstrap Dropdown Angular2 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Is it a problem with my browser that this dropdown is not working?

I wanted to add a dropdown menu in a navbar in one of my projects and it wasn't opening, so i took the example from bootstrap and it doesn't even work in a code snippet on jsfiddle.net . I am using Angular2

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You are not using ng2-bootstrap/ngx-bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working, just add the `.js` file of Bootstrap and `jquery.min.js`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Dropdown requires **Jquery** and **bootstrap.js** to be included in the page.

In **Angular**, you will not be requiring **JQuery**. But, **bootstrap.js** is fully dependent on **JQuery**.

So the alternative for bootstrap.js in Angular is **ngx-bootstrap**(https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap). By adding ngx-bootstarp as a dependency to your project will help you. Thanks for Volarkin for developing it.

Example http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue that Nav bar dropdown not working. I fixed it by following the below steps.

In Angular.json add below lines

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",  
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        ]

"styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ]
```

Because bootstrap has dependencies on both jquery and popper.js